# single quote to double quote , and , double quote to single quote in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change

every single quote to double quote 
and
every double quote to single quote

in jquery or js.

```
var myString = " tes't tes\"t tes\"t te'st ";
console.log(myString);

for (i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
    console.log(myString[i]);
    if (myString[i] == "'") {
        myString[i] == "\"";
            continue;
    }
    if (myString[i] == "\"") {
        myString[i] == "'";
            continue;
    }
}

console.log(myString);
```

But my function is not working well.
Please correct me.

Comment: What is working wrong? What result are you getting?

Comment: Btw, instead of using those both `continue` statements you could make an `else if` statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `if`s you're not doing an assignment (`myString[i] == "\"";`) but a comparsion. This should probably be a single `=`. Only problem is, strings are immutable and thus this would not work as expected. Solution, build a new string:

```
function flipQuotes(str) {
  var result = [], i = 0, lim = str.length, c;

  for (; i < lim; i += 1) {
    c = str.charAt(i);
    switch(c) {
      case '"':
        result.push("'");
        break;

      case "'":
        result.push('"');
        break;

      default:
        result.push(c);
    }
  }

  return result.join('');
}

var myString = " tes't tes\"t tes\"t te'st ";
console.log(
  flipQuotes(myString) // => ' tes"t tes't tes't te"st '
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing comparations, not assingments. Also, you can't change a string that way, you need to create a new one:

```
var myString = " tes't tes\"t tes\"t te'st ";
    console.log(myString);
    var str = [];

    for (i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
        console.log(myString[i]);
        if (myString[i] == "'") {
            str.push("\"");
        }
        else if (myString[i] == "\"") {
            str.push("'");
            continue;
        }
       else
      {
        str.push(myString[i]);
      }
    }
    str.join("");

    console.log(str);
```

Check it in [this live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tgvht/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Besides the incorrect use of `==` operator, you have another problem in your code:

`myString[i]` can be used to get the *ith* character of the string (in most browsers); but it cannot be used to "change" that character. This will work:

```
var a = myString[i];
```

This won't:

```
myString[i] = a;
```

Here is your code, re-written with minor changes plus the use of [`charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) and [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to read and change characters of string:

```
var myString = " tes't tes\"t tes\"t te'st ";
console.log(myString);
for (i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
    if (myString.charAt(i) == "'") {
        myString = myString.substring(0, i) + '"' + myString.substring(i + 1);
    } else if (myString.charAt(i) == '"') {
        myString = myString.substring(0, i) + "'" + myString.substring(i + 1);
    }
}
console.log(myString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more solution using different approach:

```
var myString = " tes't t%es\"t tes\"t te'st ",
result = myString.replace(/%/g, '\\%')
.replace(/'/g, '%')
.replace(/"/g, "'")
.replace(/[^\\]%/g, function (m) {
   return m[0] + '"';
})
.replace('\\%', '%');
```

Comment: And now you have 2 problems ;) http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html

Answer (score 1):

First, strings are immutable, any operation on strings like `.replace()` actually returns a new string. You can NOT do the following:

```
myString[ i ] = "x";
```

Your other mistake was using a comparison operator as assignment operator.

```
myString[ i ] == "x";
```

Knowing this, you need to construct a new string and replace the value of `myString` with the new value. One way of constructing a string is using the `.split('')` method to create an array representation of the string, perform mutations on the array and then revert back to string using the `.join('')` method of the array.

```
var myString = " tes't tes\"t tes\"t te'st ";
var tokens = myString.split('');

for (i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
  if (tokens[i] == "'") {
    tokens[i] = "\"";
    continue;
  }
  if (tokens[i] == "\"") {
    tokens[i] = "'";
    continue;
  }
}
myString = tokens.join('');
console.log(myString);
```